# Multiple websites hosted on one Google Apps account

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

Just so that I understand this correctly.

I would like to get a Google Apps account where I can develop many websites and host them all on that one account. (I'm not referring to Google Sites)

Is this possible or must I register a new Google Apps account for each website?

Comment: Are you trying to host multiple sites under one GAE application? Yes, that's possible, either via Modules or via handling the requests to different domains manually in the request handler. Are you asking whether you can have multiple apps in one Google account? Yes, you get up to 25 free apps per account.

Comment: I know I can make multiple apps at the .appspot.com domain but can I verify and map 25 domain to those apps?

Comment: I am not aware of any limits on multiple domain verification and as I mentioned in my first comment, yes, you can handle requests to multiple domains within one app either automatically via [Modules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/) or manually via your framework's request handler. As an example I have 3 different domains with multiple subdomains pointing to ONE gae app divided into 3 modules with each module serving different content (main website, mobile website, api interface).

Comment: If you could answer the question I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments above:

- Each Google account can create up to 25 free GAE apps or unlimited paid or premier apps.
- Each app can have multiple verified domains which can server multiple websites with different content.

It looks like you need to handle multiple website within ONE app. Once all the domains are verified, there are at least two ways of doing so:

**1. You can create a new Module for each website. This will keep things a little better organized. Each website will be in its own folder and run in its own instance. There will be a single `dispatch.yaml` which will redirect the requests depending what domain they came to i.e.:**

> ```
> dispatch:
> - url: "wwww.example1.com/*"
> module: website1
>
> - url: "wwww.example2.com/*"
> module: website2
> ```

Read more:

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing

Note that `dispatch.yaml` can only have 10 routing rules.  Also, free apps can have up to 5 modules and paid apps can have up to 20 modules. So if you plan to host more than 5 (module limits) websites on a free app or 10 websites (route limits) this might not work well for you so see option #2 which potentially doesn't have any limits although requires more manual work and the websites will be running on the same instances..

**2. You can simply use your framework's route handlers to see what domain the request came to and depending on that make a decision manually and give it a particular website's handler i.e. in Python/webapp2 it would be like this:**

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import routes

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([

    routes.DomainRoute('www.example1.com', [
        webapp2.Route('/', handler=Example1SiteHomepageHandler, name='example1-home'),
    ]),

    routes.DomainRoute('www.example2.com', [
        webapp2.Route('/', handler=Example2SiteHomepageHandler, name='example2-home'),
    ]),

])
```

Read more:

- https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html

Comment: You have answered my question plus a lot more. Thank you.